# PHP dimensional array to Javascript array WITHOUT JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert a PHP multidimensional array to a javascript array **WITHOUT using json** encoder because of the version of the server.

Exemple of a multidimensional Array :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => Région Grand EST
            [2] => GE )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => Région Grand OUEST / NORD
            [2] => GO N )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => Région Grand OUEST / SUD
            [2] => GO S )
)
```

Currently for **no multidimensional array** i'm using this function :

```php
function js_str($s) {
    return '"'  . addcslashes($s, "\0..\37\"\\") . '"';
}

function js_array($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $temp = array_map('js_str', $array);
        return '[' . implode(',', $temp) . ']';
    }
    return '[-1]';
}
```

But i can't use it for multidimensional, i'm trying to do somthing similar recursively to do it with any size of array.

To get a result like :

```
myArray = [[18, 'Région Grand EST', 'GE'],[17, 'Grand OUEST / NORD', 'GO N'], [25, 'Région Grand OUEST / SUD', 'GO S']];
```

It's really hard to find an answer without json_encode, thanks for your help.
(Yes i'm developping on a prehistoric server)

Comment: Why not am external library that creates a JSON? https://packagist.org/search/?q=JSON

Comment: "Because of server version" is a pretty weak reason against using JSON. There's *gotta* be external libraries for virtually any PHP version that provide a JSON encoder. You're basically in the process of poorly reinventing one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem with a recursive function like this:

```
function js_array($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $temp = array();
        $output = '[';
        foreach ($array AS $key=>$value) {
            $temp[] .= "'$key':" . js_array($value);
        }
        $output .= implode(',', $temp);
        $output .= "]";
    } else {
        $output .= "'$array'";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

What we're doing here is evaluating each element of the array to see if it is also an array. Each level drills down into itself until we are left with simple key:value pairs.

You can edit for special characters or to drop the array keys if you want.

Comment: Thx to you ! (arrays not working with keys so i create object if i need one with "{}" and it seems that you have a mistake on <<$output .= "'$array'";>> it's $output = "'$array'";)

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Danielml01 for his help.
Here the solution used :

```
function js_array($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $temp = array();
        $isObject = false;
        foreach ($array AS $key=>$value) {
            if (is_numeric($key))
                $temp[] .= js_array($value);
            else { 
                $isObject = true;
                $temp[] .= "'$key':" . js_array($value)."";
            }
        }
        if ($isObject)
            $output = "{".implode(',', $temp)."}";
        else
            $output = "[".implode(',', $temp)."]";
    }
    else
        $output = "'".$array."'";
    return $output;
}
```